# How to properly filter the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello everyone there is an array of data of this kind

```
const arrayPat = [
    {pat: '111', res: 'qwe', tag: '1'},
    {pat: '111', res: 'sda', tag: '2'},
    {pat: '111', res: 'xzc', tag: '3'},
    {pat: '111', res: 'cej', tag: '4'},
    {pat: '222', res: 'qwd', tag: '5'},
    {pat: '222', res: 'asd', tag: '6'},
  ]
```

need to get something like that

```
  const resultArray: any = [{pat: '111', res: ['qwe', 'sda', 'xzc', 'cej'], tag: '1'},{pat: '222', res: ['qwe', 'asd'], tag: '1'}]
```

Comment: Why that `tag` value is same in both cases?  Please also include your attempted code.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: tags are not important to me, they should not be unique
now I use array methods and loops, but I lose the sequence somewhere and it does not work correctly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If exactly what is mentioned in the question is needed, we can slightly tweak the code

```js
const arrayPat = [{
    pat: '111',
    res: 'qwe',
    tag: '1'
  },
  {
    pat: '111',
    res: 'sda',
    tag: '2'
  },
  {
    pat: '111',
    res: 'xzc',
    tag: '3'
  },
  {
    pat: '111',
    res: 'cej',
    tag: '4'
  },
  {
    pat: '222',
    res: 'qwd',
    tag: '5'
  },
  {
    pat: '222',
    res: 'asd',
    tag: '6'
  },
]
const val = []
arrayPat.forEach((curr) => {
  let newPath = val.find(currentItem => currentItem.pat === curr.pat);
  if (!newPath) {
    val.push({
      pat: curr.pat,
      res: [curr.res],
      tag: curr.tag
    })
  } else {
    newPath.res.push(curr.res)
  }

});

console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need array.reduce instead of filter. Secondly the required value of `tag` is not clear from the question. You can modify this answer to set proper value of `tag`

```js
const arrayPat = [{
    pat: '111',
    res: 'qwe',
    tag: '1'
  },
  {
    pat: '111',
    res: 'sda',
    tag: '2'
  },
  {
    pat: '111',
    res: 'xzc',
    tag: '3'
  },
  {
    pat: '111',
    res: 'cej',
    tag: '4'
  },
  {
    pat: '222',
    res: 'qwd',
    tag: '5'
  },
  {
    pat: '222',
    res: 'asd',
    tag: '6'
  },
]

const val = arrayPat.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.pat]) {
    acc[curr.pat] = {
      pat: curr.pat,
      res: [curr.res],
      tag: curr.tag
    }
  } else {
    acc[curr.pat].res.push(curr.res)
  }


  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(Object.values(val))
```

Comment: your answer works well, thanks!))